# Is it possible to restore only a part of a sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I would like to restore only a part of my production database to my development server. Can this be done?

I'll try to explain:
We have a data warehouse in SQL 2017 using several databases. One is our raw layer where new rows are added each day and never changed. 
Each load gets an Executon_key from a sequence. All tables share the same Executon_key sequence. 
My idea is to partition the database based on this sequence, for example one partition per a few million sequence numbers. 
And each partition would have it's own filegroup. 
Sample:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DW_PartitionTest] ADD FILEGROUP FG1;
ALTER DATABASE [DW_PartitionTest] ADD FILEGROUP FG2;
ALTER DATABASE [DW_PartitionTest] ADD FILEGROUP FG3;
ALTER DATABASE [DW_PartitionTest] ADD FILEGROUP FG4;
ALTER DATABASE [DW_PartitionTest] ADD FILEGROUP FG5;

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PartFunctionExecKeyMillionRange (int)  
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (5000000, 10000000,12000000, 14000000);

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartSchemeExecKeyMillionRange  
AS PARTITION PartFunctionExecKeyMillionRange  
TO (FG1, FG2, FG3, FG4, FG5)
```

As soon as the current Execution_key > upper boundary value of a range, this partition can be set to readonly.

I want to be able to take a partial backup of this database and only restore the writable filegroups to my development server. We dont't need all data.

Is this possible to do? All my attempts so far gets me a database in "a defunct state"

Comment: No you can't do a partial backup. To accomplish what you are talking about would require a full backup and restore. Then you could deleted the objects you don't want.